# PDFBox, BBox, page number?

Tags: java, dimensions, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox, successfully to retrieve field coordinates from PDFs. Moving on to multi-page PDFs, I ran into the situation where I need to determine from which page these fields are coming from, and additionally to convert the coordinates from bottom-up to top-down. I've read through numerous pages of the doc to find a method that would work, most return null, or fail, and there are no results upon search.

What am I looking for? Document outline? BBbos? mediaBox? cropBox?

And for page number, a few other libraries have such simply titled methods as getCurrentPageNo(). Would I need to:

```
List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
  for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
  // etc for each one?
}
```

This is such a core ability, I'm somewhat surprised I haven't found an example yet.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
PDPage page = .........
PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
System.out.println( "Width:" + mediaBox.getWidth() );
System.out.println( "Height:" + mediaBox.getHeight() )
```

for the page number:

```
page.getCOSDictionary().equals(page))
```

Comment: The last fragment "for the page number" is wrong or unclear?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it turned out to be wrong, never increments past page 1. Still no clue.

Comment: Do you need the "real" page number - the one printed on the page, possibly non-numeric - or just the ordinal page number (1-n)?

Comment: I ended up just using the index of the interation routin I was using, works well enough. thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Were you able to find out if a field existed on a particular page?